# Dominosa- container classes C++

Tags: c++

I'm doing an exercise- Dominosa- where I have to use recursive backtracking to solve Dominosa boards. On a board of random numbers, the numbers need to be paired, no pairing can be repeated.

The problem is that the class header files don't seem to allow the use of the container classes- or at least not in the way that I'm trying to. So far I've tried sets within sets, maps within sets, vectors within sets etc- to keep track of pairs of numbers that have been selected. But I always get the error "Invalid operands to binary expression", which links to this;

```
 /// One of the @link s20_3_3_comparisons comparison functors@endlink.
      template <class _Tp>
       struct less : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
        {
          bool
          operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
          { return __x < __y; }
       };
```

Which is in stl_function.h. So this;

```
Map<coord, int> numbers;
```

doesnt create an error, whilst this;

```
Set<Set<Map<coord, int> > > pairings;
```

Creates an error.

Currently I don't see how to solve this without keeping track of pairings...?

Comment: Since I've not a clue what `Set` and `Map` are (as opposed to `std::set<>` and `std::map<>`) I could only fathom guesses as to what the problem is. Can you tell us anything about those classes? The error your getting is likely because those classes require a comparator, defaulting to `std::less<T>` which uses whatever `operator <()` is defined for the mapped type. Since there is none for your `Map` or `Set` type, the code cannot compile.

Comment: Map stores the number (int) on the tile on the board, with the tile's coordinate (coord) as key. I was trying to store them in sets of pairs, within a set. So that I can easily check the set to see if a pair is there. I've also tried Set<Set<int> > just storing the number combinations without the coordinates.

Comment: That sounds like the problem- but what is a comparator, scuse my ignorance. Oh wait... Google....

Comment: @RobbieCooper: Did you mean `std::set` and `std::map`? If so, please fix the case. All symbols in standard library have lower-case names.

Comment: Maybe I didn't say that in a way that made sense. Take #2: sets and maps are **ordered** collections. They establish that order by comparing keys (which, in a set's case, is also the object. they're one in the same). The comparison uses the default comparator `std::less<>` which eventually reduces down to an `a < b` comparison to determine order unless you provide something different. The compiler hasn't a clue how to "compare" one one set with another to determine which is "less" than the other. So you get the error you're getting now. You may need to rethink your model.

Comment: I'm using namespace std and XCode corrects me if I use different cases on the names. I think WhozCraig is right- its about comparators, but not sure how to use such a thing to make this work..

Comment: What is a `set<set<whatever> >` supposed to solve? A set allows you to query whether it contains a value and iterate across the values it contains. So you can query the outer set for whether it contains a particular inner set. But it does not see into the inner set, so you can't query it whether it contains a set that contains something.

Comment: Ok. Definitely need to rethink. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are close to a model (in your head), but unwind your stack (no pun intended) and think a little more. Is this supposed to maintain state of multiple "versions" of the same board, or just a single instance of a single board. The latter is more trivial than you may thing, the former a little harder, but not too difficult.

Comment: Single instance- so now I'm thinking of just having a vector of vectors and store the pairings in that.

Comment: You may not need even that. If all you need is a way to ensure each *pair* is distinct (i.e. {a,b} {a,c}, {b,c} is ok, but {a,b}, {a,b} is not) you only need a single `std::set<>`. The standard library provides a very hand `operator <()` for the generic `std::pair<>` class, which may well make this *very* easy for you.

Comment: But how do you define them as pairs? As it stands they are units that can be combined in different ways. Surely they need to be stored in something as pairs, and then put in the set?

Comment: Hang on, I didnt catch that last bit. I'll check out that operator and class- never heard of them before...

Comment: Yes, that definitely helps alot! Thanks

Comment: Very glad it helped. For a really lame sample of how to use pairs in a set, take a look at [this code](http://ideone.com/DmA5gI). Hope it works for you (and sorry for the really lame sample).